# How to do fulltext search on multiple collections at same time in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, search, elasticsearch, full-text-search

Right now we are using MongoDB

Lets support there is 100 million users profile . In user profile we have

a) username
b) firstname
c) lastname
d) phonenumber
e) address:{city, state, country etc} 
f) description 
g) likes (array list)
h) gender etc

Another Collection of Jobs , jobs fields are -:

a) jobTitle
b) jobDescritption
c) minPackage
d) maxPackage
e) jobLocation etc

Similarly we have collections for Tasks, Events etc

There is different searches for different collection for Example Jobs have it own search View and user set the search filters and we easily make query for them.

But now on front page there is common search Box and we have to do the full text search on Every collection **Ex**  If user type any thing than it do fulltext search from every collection (User,Job, Task etc).

My question is MongoDB is for this purpose Or we have to use Elastic Search or any other Technology

Comment: Text search on MongoDB are only within a single collection, so you'll have to merge (so introducing a denormalization) the relevant data within it. On the other hand, it would be a denormalization even replicating data on a third engine (the external text indexing service).

Historically it was somewhat required pairing MongoDB with Solr or ElasticSearch because text indexes didn't existed on the first, but now it becomes an opinion-based A-or-B question, so it's impossible to answer in an objective way: there are very good reasons to adopt both solutions, depending from your context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have previously paired MongoDB and Solr with great success. There are some tools which will try to keep Solr and MongoDB in sync by following the oplog, but I haven't used them. Instead my application code made sure to send the required documents to Solr when they changed.

Comment: Second answer that is not an answer ( the other is already deleted ). This is a comment and nothing more ( even well short enough to fit ). The question is clearly "off-topic" asking for your opinion on what is "best" here. It would be "best" to just leave it alone at let the eventual closure sort that out for the OP. Or leave a comment instead.

Comment: I disagree with it being clearly off-topic - it might as well be a non-native English speaker struggling with formulating a question. It does look like a "what is best" question, but might easily be a "how do I do full text search in MongoDB" question. Why not ask OP to clarify or re-formulate?

Comment: Elastic Search is better option for this problem ?

Comment: @Martin: why not ask them to reformulate and *then* answer the question? That is why we put questions on hold, to make sure they are clear and suitable for the site. If the OP edits, it can be reopened. If this really is a *how do I do full text search* it sounds like an overly broad question to me.